# Postar código funcional no stackoverflow visando uma refatoração?

Tags: debate

É **on-topic** postar código que está funcionando no [pt.stackoverflow.com](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) visando uma melhoria / refatoração do mesmo? Penso que foge ao escopo, porém como não temos um [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), este tipo de pergunta seria passível de vista grossa?

Exemplo de perguntas do codereview:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/is-this-a-good-controller
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23821/how-to-optimize-the-pagination-query
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23469/cakephp-best-strategy-for-getting-habtm-data-in-multiple-ways-within-the-same-to

> **Adicionei a pergunta em questão do codereview para o pt.stackoverflow.**

- [CakePHP deixar "action" e "template" mais conciso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101511/cakephp-deixar-action-e-template-mais-conciso)

Comment: Relacionado => [É aceitável fazer uma pergunta pedindo opiniões sobre um código e como deixá-lo mais eficiente?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4585/91)

Comment: Não vejo porque seria um problema... Não quero dizer que *não será fechada*, mas sim que *não deveria ser fechada*.

Comment: Outra relacionada: [Por que duvidas baseadas em opiniões/trocar ideias sobre códigos não são aceitas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4210/91)

Comment: Eu diria que a pergunta seria bem ou mal recebida dependendo de como ela for feita. Se for bem explicado e um desafio interessante várias pessoas vão responder. Se for um código mal escrito, sem contexto, difícil de entender o que é esperado e incompleto (classes faltando e métodos que tenho que adivinhar o que fazem), creio que a pergunta vai ser fechada.

Comment: Acho que sim, já vi duas perguntas aqui muito bem aceitas que usavam a tag [tag:revisão-código]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que pode ser aceitável caso o contexto seja bem descrito.

Para ser aceitável, acho que tem que ser algo bem descrito onde atraia interesse de outros usuários como se fosse um desafio e algo que realmente valesse a pena pela experiência e aprendizado e benéfico a nível comunitário ao invés de tornar-se meramente a refatoração de um código gratuitamente ou fazer o trabalho alheio sem oneração ou específico para o interesse de uma única pessoa.

Todavia, é raro que tópicos desse tipo sejam bem descritos. A grande maioria são espertinhos esperando que algum inocente faça o seu trabalho de graça.

Infelizmente a maioria se aproveita da ingenuidade dos usuários e joga códigos imensos na pergunta e ficam esperando que algum inocente vá lá e faça o trabalho dele de graça.

Tem que saber discernir qual o limite entre o que é ajudar ou agregar valor comunitário e, o que é fazer um trabalho alheio de graça, feito bobo.

Não tenho nada contra quem quer trabalhar de graça feito bobo, pois cada um faz o que bem entender. O que eu não concordo nisso, é que desvaloriza a si mesmo e o mercado em geral.

Aquele que se dispõe a resolver (trabalhar de graça), terá algum ganho com a experiência. Isso é óbvio. Mas é óbvio também que trabalhou de graça feito bobo e contribuiu para desvalorizar a si mesmo e ao mercado.

Comment: [Isso não é um code review](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98756/91)